# pyflink, ImportError: No module named pyflink

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

I am testing pyflink on

- os: centos7
- flink version: flink-1.14.3
- virtualenv python version: Python 3.6.8

pip list:

- apache-beam            2.27.0
- apache-flink           1.14.3
- apache-flink-libraries 1.14.3
- avro-python3           1.9.2.1
- certifi                2021.10.8
- charset-normalizer     2.0.11
- cloudpickle            1.2.2
- crcmod                 1.7
- dill                   0.3.1.1
- docopt                 0.6.2
- fastavro               0.23.6
- future                 0.18.2
- grpcio                 1.43.0
- hdfs                   2.6.0
- httplib2               0.17.4
- idna                   3.3
- mock                   2.0.0
- numpy                  1.19.5
- oauth2client           4.1.3
- pandas                 1.1.5
- pbr                    5.8.1
- pip                    21.3.1
- protobuf               3.17.3
- py4j                   0.10.8.1
- pyarrow                2.0.0
- pyasn1                 0.4.8
- pyasn1-modules         0.2.8
- pydot                  1.4.2
- pyflink                1.0
- pymongo                3.12.3
- pyparsing              3.0.7
- python-dateutil        2.8.0
- pytz                   2021.3
- requests               2.27.1
- rsa                    4.8
- setuptools             59.6.0
- six                    1.16.0
- typing-extensions      3.7.4.3
- urllib3                1.26.8
- wheel                  0.37.1

I tried to run this command :

- (virtualenv) [myuser@myvm flink-1.14.3] ./bin/flink run -py examples/python/table/word_count.py
  And got the following error:

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to execute the command: python -c import pyflink;import os;print(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(pyflink.**file**)), 'bin'))
output: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named pyflink

I am sure pyflink package is already installed. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3):

To install PyFlink, you only need to execute:

python -m pip install apache-flink

and make sure you have a compatible Python version (>= 3.5).

The problem may be the Python Virtual Environment， refer to https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/python/faq/#preparing-python-virtual-environment

Also may be you can add option '-pyexec venv.zip/venv/bin/python3' and have a try

Comment: '-pyexec' work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if pyflink is well installed (in your venv)

also check if you are running Flink

if no, start it with :

```
start-cluster.sh
```

here is full documentation about PyFlink:
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/python/overview/